# Why is it returning false?

Tags: javascript

```
function validPhone(phoneNum) {
 var reg = new RegExp("^\d{3}-\d{4}$");
 if (reg.test(phoneNum)) {
     return "True";
 }
 else {
     return "False";
  }
 }
//main code\\
 <html>
 <head>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="codechallenge3.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script>
 var phoneNum = "555-555";
 document.write("Check the following phone number: ", phoneNum, " = ",  validPhone(phoneNum), "<br>");
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

//Why does it keep returning false? I've tried to fix it , but it's not returning true.\

Comment: 555-555 isn't a valid phone number according to the RegEx?

Comment: Try `555-5555` ;)

Comment: You are checking a `"^\d{3}-\d{3}$"` matching string against a regex that expects 4 digits after the `-`

Comment: Try this string: 123-1234

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is looking for 4 digits not 3.  Try 555-5555

Answer (score 1):

Valid phone number would be ddd-dddd where d is a digit.

Comment: @510am, if the solution is working for you, please Accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

1. Change

   ```
   var phoneNum = "555-555";
   ```

   to

   ```
   var phoneNum = "555-5555";
   ```

   if you want to have 4 digits in the second group.
2. Change

   ```
   var reg = new RegExp("^\d{3}-\d{4}$");
   ```

   to

   ```
   var reg = new RegExp("^\\d{3}-\\d{4}$");
   ```

   or to

   ```
   var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$");
   ```

   or to

   ```
   var reg = /^\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
   ```